# Proper architecture/pattern to use redis-rq as remote task runner

Tags: python, ssh, redis, queue, multitasking

I am doing research that requires me to run multiple experiments with many permutations of parameters. My main issue is that I would like to free up my main machine for my daily tasks and offload my experiments to other machines (I have two extra laptops).

Currently I am using redis-rq to queue and run tasks on those "remote servers". Once redis is running on my main machine and my remote servers, I simply run my code which queues the tasks to the specific redis-rq port on my remote (via ssh). This seems to work fine except that I need to make sure to push my code to my remote server before doing this otherwise the task will fail. The remote will essentially have old code on it.

I have two questions:

- Does this pattern make sense or is there a better way for me to offload tasks to remote servers?
- Is there a way I can ensure the remote always has up-to-date code when I start queueing tasks? (currently thinking of including a function in my code that will copy the current directory to the remote via scp)

Thanks for your help with this,

NB: my code is all in **python** and would prefer to keep it that way

Comment: Why don't you simply write your code in the remote server and run it there as well? You don't necessarily need to use your own laptop.

Comment: This is likely idealistic for no justifiable reason but I'd rather not have to interact with my remote server physically.. i.e. store it somewhere away from my overflowing desk...